# Windows Form Height Inconsistency

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7, windows-8.1

I am seeing some weird inconsistencies with a fixed size Windows form between Windows 7 and Windows 8.1. I have have the form size set to 1280X760. When I debug on Windows 7 the form stays true to size. However, when I run the same application on Windows 8.1, the form resizes itself to 1280X706. I have tried changing the height to 800 and it runs as 743, at 825 it runs at 758.

I thought maybe there is some vertical scaling happening somewhere but the size change isn't linear so it is likely not a scaling factor.

Has anyone else experienced this strange behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled across the answer myself.

There is a form property "**AutoScaleMode**". This property is set to "**Font**" by default. Setting this to "**None**" fixes this. Apparently there is a some font scaling happening when running the application on a Tablet PC.